# Chrome frequently crashes on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I have the same problem in chrome and chromium. At some point chrome just crashes. Any idea what could cause this? All extensions are disabled.

```
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Onscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Onscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230536:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Onscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Onscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Onscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9771)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_EXT
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[14239:14239:1202/230537:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3055)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this particular issue is caused by hardware acceleration. My suggestion is to turn off hardware acceleration in the Chrome settings.